# How to get text of node in dart/flutter

Tags: xml, dart, flutter

I have responseText like

```
<root><message>This is message</message></root>.
```

When I do this script:

```
var xmlDoc = xml.parse(value);
_msg = xmlDoc.findAllElements('message').toString();
```

The result is:

```
<message>This is message</message>
```

How can I get only the 'This is message' (without the elements)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document says you should call `text` to extract text contents.

https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml#traversing-and-querying

This will work. (Note that `msg` is an Array of String)

```dart
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;

main() {
  final value = "<root><message>This is message</message></root>";
  final xmlDoc = xml.parse(value);
  final msg = xmlDoc.findAllElements('message').map((node) => node.text);
  print(msg.first);
}
```

Comment: why the result is always in the '()'? Thanks.

Comment: It is because `msg` is an Array of String, not single String. Use `first` to get the string value. I updated my answer to contain all of my code.